# How to add health check for topics in KafkaStreams api

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a critical Kafka application that needs to be up and running all the time. The source topics are created by debezium kafka connect for mysql binlog. Unfortunately, many things can go wrong with this setup. A lot of times debezium connectors fail and need to be restarted, so does my apps then (because without throwing any exception it just hangs up and stops consuming). My manual way of testing and discovering the failure is checking kibana log, then consume the suspicious topic through terminal. I can mimic this in code but obviously no way the best practice. I wonder if there is the ability in KafkaStream api that allows me to do such health check, and check other parts of kafka cluster?
Another point that bothers me is if I can keep the stream alive and rejoin the topics when connectors are up again.

Comment: Can you setup alerts in Elasticsearch/Kibana? If you want to automate health checks, focus on setting those up to restart services

Comment: @cricket_007 This was my fall back plan but now seems my only way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [Kafka Streams State](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.State.html) to see if it is rebalancing/running, which would indicate healthy operations. Although, if no data is getting into the Topology, I would assume there would be no errors happening, so you need to then lookup the health of your upstream dependencies.

Overall, sounds like you might want to invest some time into using monitoring tools like Consul or Sensu which can run local service health checks and send out alerts when services go down. Or at the very least [Elasticseach alerting](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-alerting)

As far as Kafka health checking goes, you can do that in several ways

1. Is the broker and zookeeper process running? (SSH to the node, check processes)
2. Is the broker and zookeeper ports open? (use Socket connection)
3. Are there important JMX metrics you can track? ([Metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/blog/brewing-in-beats-add-support-for-jolokia-lmx))
4. Can you find an active Controller broker (use `AdminClient#describeCluster`)
5. Are there a required minimum number of brokers you would like to respond as part of the Controller metadata (which can be obtained from `AdminClient`)
6. Are the topics that you use having the proper configuration? (retention, min-isr, replication-factor, partition count, etc)? (again, use `AdminClient`)